# Need help identifying replacement Magic Smoke Container

Tags: resistors, diodes, components, identification

Was doing some electrical work, plugged in a charger for an LED work light, the thing goes *foof*, charging is not happening so much right now.

I took the charger apart, and the *only* thing that looks even remotely in a *post-foof* state is the one pictured (the board itself appears undamaged, albeit scorched). I'm assuming it's a resistor, but I don't claim to be certain, and I don't know which size/rating. There is a black band at the bottom and a brown band at the top, and I don't think there are any bands gone missing since "the incident".

Can you identify it, so that I can replace it and see if that revives the charger? I would like that very much.

The charger is marked as "110-230V, 0.3A" with output rating of "5V 1500mA".

Photos:

Top side 1

[image]

top side 2

[image]

bottom side (component is between indicated holes)

[image]

Comment: Looks like a fuse, but it probably blew because something else on the board failed.

Comment: Don't say that ... I don't know how to identify what that would be. :(

Comment: It IS a fuse. Look at the silkscreen: "F1" and a graphic symbol for a fuse.

Comment: smells like a 10 Ohm resistor to me, that was cheaper than a fuse, but inadequate for surge charge current under load

Comment: Huh, thanks. I only knew about the fuse symbol here: [the left one of these two](https://ludens.cl/Electron/audioamps/fuse2.png).

Comment: The fuse is gone, but we don't know why. One thing to check for sure is each diode in the bridge rectifier (four legs, D1). It's not unusual for one or more of these to be dead short in both directions, which means a new bridge. After that you might be OK ... or not.

Comment: _"post-foof"_ - Heh :P

Comment: @BrianDrummond, I've measured D1. Across two sets of pins (call 'em a-b and b-c), I get 0Ω one way and no connection the other way. Across two other sets (b-c and c-d) I get either no connection or a *brief* connection (of about 40-80Ω), then nothing. This doesn't scream "I'm working fine" at me.

Comment: It is most likely a 'fusible resistor' - that is a resistor with defined fusing ability. Very common in consumer gear for this very application. I agree with the other - something else has failed to cause the fusistor to do its job. Someone has to take one for the team.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do two separate trouble shooting:

You could try measuring the resistance on the LED block contacts to see if it is not shorted. If multimeter shows "0" resistance, it is shorted. If is it not shorted, you could try next (since the device is powered from ac power mains, you should not work with it with no experience):

The power supply's enclosure must specify the current rating of the supply. So, you need to estimate the fuse rating for replacement. Then you could try plug it in again, but without the load (no LED block). If no "foof" happens, then **maybe** the device is not damaged, and you could try connecting the LED block again, hoping that the first time there was some accidental temporary short.

My guess:

The text YS-388-10W indicates the model number and perhaps the output power rating 10 watt. So, if this charger works from  110V, then the current necessary to provide the 10W would be 10/110=90mA. You can try to find the fuse that is 100mA rated and try replacing the burnt one.

Comment: It's marked as "110-230V, 0.3A" with output rating of "5V 1500mA".

Comment: Find a new 0.3A 230V fuse. It does not have to be in a shape of the resistor. As long as you can properly install it on the board, you can use any shape.

Comment: I've measured across the two "exit" pads, and get a brief connection of about 80-200Ω, then no connection.

Comment: You should measure the input pads of the LED block (or whatever it is), not the exit pads of the charger.

Comment: Sorry, I mis-read. The LED lamp is working fine when used with its internal battery (that I can no longer charge). Across its input pins,  I get zero connection whatsoever.

Comment: Well, than at least you can conclude that it is not shorted. Try replacing the fuse. As for the "zero connection", I would expect it to have at least some high resistance. Maybe in the MOhm range? what range of the multimeter did you use? Could the wire that connects the charger with the LED be damaged and shorted?